# Animating a 3D model with XNA

Tags: xna, animation, 3d-meshes, 3dsmax, biped

How do I animate a biped model from 3ds max using XNA framework or not necessarily the biped model, it could be any 3D model but how can I code the animation?

Comment: http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/skinned_model

Comment: If the model geometry is broken down into the typical hierarchical series of sub meshes (ModelMesh & ModelMeshParts) and does not include a skeleton specifically built in 3ds max, this sample may be more useful:  http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/simple_animation

Comment: If you have access to the vertex data you could write your own Bone Animation system (which would make you feel like a boss.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply **export your annimation from 3DS Max** to a file type by supproter "XNA" (**fx, fbx, etc. ..)** And import your annimation in your project xna with "importer". (see the sample in the use of Microsoft [Skinned model annim sample](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/skinned_model)).

Many existing tutorial to convert a model from 3ds Max to annimé xna .. Here is one:

[Tuto 3ds Max to Xna model anim](http://www.3dtotal.com/index_tutorial_detailed.php?id=492)